# always getting 6a82 and 6d00 for reading visa emv card

Tags: java, smartcard, smartcard-reader, emv, smartcardio

i am reading data from visa card but always getting response 6a82 and 6d00 for PSE.
I am using smartcardio and following are the commands
Select PSE:
00A404000E315041592E5359532E444446303100

Processing code:
80A8000002830000

Below code works fine for [paypak](https://1link.net.pk/pay-pak/) (a Pakistan payment card claiming EMV compatibility) but for visa its not working.

```py
startCardConnection("0");
    String commandVisa = "00A4040007A000000003101000";
    String command_PSE = "00A404000E315041592E5359532E444446303100";
     String command_getProcessingOptionsVISA = "80A8000002830000";
    String response;
    response = executeCardCommand(command_PSE);
    response = executeCardCommand(commandVisa);
    readCardRecords(2);
    response = executeCardCommand(command_getProcessingOptionsVISA);
response = executeCardCommand("80AE8000210000000000000000000000000586000000000005861802020000E44E4B11040001");


  public static String executeCardCommand(String command) {
    if (transmissionTrace)
        System.out.println("SYS: Executing card command:" + command);

    capdu = makeCommandAPDU(command);
    TLV tagsList;
    try {
        if (card == null) {
        System.out.println("SYS: ERR: Card not present/not responding!");
        return null;
        }
        responsedAPDU = card.getBasicChannel().transmit(capdu);

        showRes(responsedAPDU.getBytes());

        tagsList = new TLV(responsedAPDU.getBytes());
        allTagsTLV.getChildren().add(tagsList);
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>" + responsedAPDU.toString());

    } catch (CardException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TLVException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("SYS: NO tags response. May be correct if not expecting tags.");
    }

    return allTagsTLV.getJson();

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Support for PSE for contact is optional - both for cards as well as for terminals. From the terminal/kernel perspective only LoA (List of AIDs) method is obligatory. As described in detail by EMV Book 1 chapter 12.3, when PSE is missing (status word 6A82), terminal should build candidate list using List of AIDs method basing on its configuration. I don't know when you are getting 6D00, but you don't perform application selection correctly, so I guess you are firing the commands like GPO and GenAC with no application selected. The code you are quoting is very wrong - it does not handle any errors, does not select application correctly, it does not check for PDOL presence, does not read records with CDOL1, does not build DOLs. Quite honestly it may work by coincidence only.